# Writing a for-loop using psql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I am trying to run a for loop via [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) command in Linux to do some spatial operations in PostGIS database

My SQL command which I successfully ran in dbeaver looks something like this

```
DO $$
declare
    the_name varchar(50);

BEGIN 

FOR the_name IN
        SELECT "name" FROM myschema.mytable WHERE "idcolumn" = 'selected id' LIMIT 4
LOOP  

some operations inside the loop...

END LOOP;
RAISE NOTICE 'the name - (%)', the_name; 
END; 
$$;
```

I usually copy-paste the dbeaver SQL command inside `psql -c` and it runs fine. But I am getting a syntax error when using the above code. I am a beginner in SQL and any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**

This is the error message - it's weird because I don't have this number in the code. It's probably reading from memory or something.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "377643"
LINE 1: DO 377643 declare the_name varchar(50); BEGIN FOR the_...
```

Comment: And the syntax error is? Have you tried putting the code in a file and doing `psql -f <file_name>? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: I have added the error. What should be the format of the file? .sh?

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward, the issue is with `377643`. Where is that coming from? It is not in the code snippet you show. The file is just a text file. I usually name them <some_name>.sql so I know they contain SQL statements.

Comment: It's not straightforward. What I wrote in my code is exactly what is presented here. Actually, I found a solution and will post it here soon.